# Unable to create initial connection pool in Grails 3

Tags: intellij-idea, grails3, intellij-17

I have a  grails 3.2.7 application with Intellij IDEA 2017.1.1. But the problem is I couldn't create a connection pool to my MySql database (development environment).

> Here is my application.yml

```html
---
grails:
    profile: web
    codegen:
        defaultPackage: ifp
    spring:
        transactionManagement:
            proxies: false
info:
    app:
        name: '@info.app.name@'
        version: '@info.app.version@'
        grailsVersion: '@info.app.grailsVersion@'
spring:
    main:
        banner-mode: "off"
    groovy:
        template:
            check-template-location: false

# Spring Actuator Endpoints are Disabled by Default
endpoints:
    enabled: false
    jmx:
        enabled: true

---
grails:
    mime:
        disable:
            accept:
                header:
                    userAgents:
                        - Gecko
                        - WebKit
                        - Presto
                        - Trident
        types:
            all: '*/*'
            atom: application/atom+xml
            css: text/css
            csv: text/csv
            form: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
            html:
              - text/html
              - application/xhtml+xml
            js: text/javascript
            json:
              - application/json
              - text/json
            multipartForm: multipart/form-data
            pdf: application/pdf
            rss: application/rss+xml
            text: text/plain
            hal:
              - application/hal+json
              - application/hal+xml
            xml:
              - text/xml
              - application/xml
    urlmapping:
        cache:
            maxsize: 1000
    controllers:
        defaultScope: singleton
    converters:
        encoding: UTF-8
    views:
        default:
            codec: html
        gsp:
            encoding: UTF-8
            htmlcodec: xml
            codecs:
                expression: html
                scriptlets: html
                taglib: none
                staticparts: none
endpoints:
    jmx:
        unique-names: true

---
hibernate:
    cache:
        queries: false
        use_second_level_cache: true
        use_query_cache: false
        region.factory_class: org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory

dataSource:
    pooled: true
    jmxExport: true
    driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
    username: root
    password: root

environments:
    development:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
            url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ifp;AUTO_RECONNECT=TRUE;
    test:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
            url: jdbc:mysql://192.168.40.67:3306/ifp;AUTO_RECONNECT=TRUE;
    production:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
            url: jdbc:mysql://192.168.40.67:3306/ifp;AUTO_RECONNECT=TRUE;
            properties:
                jmxEnabled: true
                initialSize: 5
                maxActive: 50
                minIdle: 5
                maxIdle: 25
                maxWait: 10000
                maxAge: 600000
                timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 5000
                minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 60000
                validationQuery: SELECT 1
                validationQueryTimeout: 3
                validationInterval: 15000
                testOnBorrow: true
                testWhileIdle: true
                testOnReturn: false
                jdbcInterceptors: ConnectionState
                defaultTransactionIsolation: 2 # TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
```

> Here is my build.gradle

```html
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsVersion"
        classpath "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-gradle:2.11.6"
        classpath "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5:${gormVersion-".RELEASE"}"
    }
}

version "0.1"
group "ifp"

apply plugin:"eclipse"
apply plugin:"idea"
apply plugin:"war"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-web"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-gsp"
apply plugin:"asset-pipeline"

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
    compile "org.grails:grails-core"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    compile "org.grails:grails-dependencies"
    compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:scaffolding"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.1.3.Final"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:5.1.3.Final"
    console "org.grails:grails-console"
    profile "org.grails.profiles:web"
    runtime "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-grails:2.11.6"
    runtime "com.h2database:h2"
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-plugin-testing"
    testCompile "org.grails.plugins:geb"
    testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:2.47.1"
    testRuntime "net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.18"

//--------------Custom Dependencies----------------
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.1.1'
    compile "org.grails.plugins:jasypt-encryption:2.0.1"
    runtime "org.grails.plugins:jquery:1.11.1"
    runtime "mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.37"

}

bootRun {
    jvmArgs('-Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always')
    addResources = true
}


assets {
    minifyJs = true
    minifyCss = true
}
```

Iam a newbi to grails 3 so can someone help me to figure out the issue?

Answer (score 0):

These dependencies seem to be missing for your build file

```
runtime "org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:8.5.0"
runtime "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-log4j:8.5.0"
```

Try adding them and see if it works.